# google side bar - are js server side global variables shared between side bar calles

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-development-server

Consider side bar simple server side script .

```
const publicArr = [];

function doWait2(ms){
   var start = new Date().getTime();
   var end = start;
                 
    while(end < start + ms) {
       end = new Date().getTime();
   }
}

function getfirstCall(){
    publicArr.push("Item1");
    doWait2(10000);
    return publicArr;
}

function getsecondCall(){
    publicArr.push("Item2");
    return publicArr;
}
```

When calling `getfirstCall` and `getsecondCall` one after another, each function returns a single item array (Item1 / Item2 respectively). Changes made by `getfirstCall` to `publicArr` are not reflected when client execute `getsecondCall`.

Note that `getfirstCall` waits 10 sec before returning allowing `getsecondCall` to be handled simultaneously by the server. not sure it is important.

Is this guarantee?
each client call gets its own instances of the public variables?

Guess this is pretty fundamental with web development, and not only with side bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Apps Script global variables are not unique across script executions, you should consider using the [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) to store your `publicArr` as a script property, retrievable by all users. And perhaps [LockService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock) if you are worried about concurrent executions.

See these answers for pointers:

[How to define global variable in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721226/how-to-define-global-variable-in-google-apps-script)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63601016/4243927

Comment: I read those before. Can you explain why I get single item array each time i make a call?

Comment: Yes, because your array is outside of any function, and "global" variables are not treated like JS in Apps Script.

Comment: **and "global" variables are not treated like JS in Apps Script** . What does it mean?

Comment: Hi there @OJNSim! Apps Script has some differences with JavaScript. [Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) you can see a deeper analysis.

Comment: @OJNSim https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime/migration#avoid_calling_functions_before_they_are_parsed